# TYPO3 Inline Relational Record Editing (IRRE)

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I created a new content element which adds a field called **heroslider** to `tt_content`.
The TCA looks like this:

```
'heroslider' => [
    'config' => [
            'type'           => 'inline',
            'allowed'        => 'tx_ext_domain_model_heroslider_item',
            'foreign_table'  => 'tx_ext_domain_model_heroslider_item',
            'foreign_field'  => 'tt_content_uid',
            'foreign_sortby' => 'sorting',
            'foreign_label'  => 'header',
            'maxitems'       => 99,
            'appearance'     => [
                    'collapseAll'  => 1,
                    'expandSingle' => 1,
            ],
    ],
],
```

Now when I add a `heroslider_item` in the BE, it gets stored properly, except for the field `tt_content_uid`. This fields contains a zero instead of the `uid` of the content element.

Do you have any idea what I am missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your table `tx_ext_domain_model_heroslider_item` you miss a field for the reverse table name. at least you have not declared it in your relation:

```
foreign_table_field = parent_table
```

You know that your parent records always are `tt_content`, but TYPO3 needs some help.

---

ANFSCD:

why do you have

```
'allowed'        => 'tx_ext_domain_model_heroslider_item',
```

I can not find any documentation about an option `allowed`.

Comment: I know this is four years old but here is why they have "allowed" in there: It is provided by this plugin https://github.com/IchHabRecht/content_defender

edit: same with "maxitems" btw